# Simple Time Comparison Multithreading Program in C++ (and 4 questions)

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, thread-safety

I have experience in C++ and I am trying to learn multithreading with the language.
I just wrote the following program (code below questions) to compare the time efficiency of running ten function calls one by one vs in parallel.

My four questions are:

1. Is this a correct usage of the thread library ? The time seems reasonable, as threading should be by far faster, but I am new to this feature and would like to be certain I did it correctly. If there are any improvements to the program, please let me know.
2. Is the output (below the code) expected ? The threads were trying to print to the console at the same time, so there were some characters being written before a new line or characters being printed with other values such as: 3 + 5 = 84 + 5 = (new line) 9, instead of 3 + 5 = 8 (new line) 4 + 5 = 9. Is this behaviour expected ?
3. Also any types of reading material or advice on this topic would be appreciated ! I have been reading articles and plan on watching some videos on multithreading soon.
4. The output time was different each time I ran it. Of course that is expected, but sometimes, the multithreaded run was slower than the one by one function call run. Is that supposed to happen?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void add(int num) {
    cout << num << " + 5 = " << num + 5 << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j;
    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    c = 2;
    d = 3;
    e = 4;
    f = 5;
    g = 6;
    h = 7;
    i = 8;
    j = 9;
    
    cout << "Starting timer for no multithreading" << endl;

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    add(a);
    add(b);
    add(c);
    add(d);
    add(e);
    add(f);
    add(g);
    add(h);
    add(i);
    add(j);
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    cout << "Stopped timer for no multithreading" << endl;

    std::chrono::duration<double> total1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1);

    cout << "Without multithreading, the ten function calls took: " << total1.count() << " seconds to complete." << endl;
    

    cout << endl << endl;

    thread A(add, a);
    thread B(add, b);
    thread C(add, c);
    thread D(add, d);
    thread E(add, e);
    thread F(add, f);
    thread G(add, g);
    thread H(add, h);
    thread I(add, i);
    thread J(add, j);

    cout << "Starting timer for multithreading" << endl;

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    A.join();
    B.join();
    C.join();
    D.join();
    E.join();
    F.join();
    G.join();
    H.join();
    I.join();
    J.join();
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    cout << "Stopped timer for multithreading" << endl;

    std::chrono::duration<double> total2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t4 - t3);

    cout << "With multithreading, the ten function calls took: " << total2.count() << " seconds to complete." << endl;
    //cout << total2 << "seconds" << endl;
    

    return 0;
}
```

The output was:

```
Starting timer for no multithreading
0 + 5 = 5
1 + 5 = 6
2 + 5 = 7
3 + 5 = 8
4 + 5 = 9
5 + 5 = 10
6 + 5 = 11
7 + 5 = 12
8 + 5 = 13
9 + 5 = 14
Stopped timer for no multithreading
Without multithreading, the ten function calls took: 0.0016732 seconds to complete.


0 + 5 = 5
1 + 5 = 6
2 + 5 = 7
3 + 5 = 84 + 5 =
9
5 + 5 = 106 + 5 = 11
7 + 5 =
12
8 + 5 = 13
Starting timer for multithreading9 + 5 = 14

Stopped timer for multithreading
With multithreading, the ten function calls took: 5.07e-05 seconds to complete.
```

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: more threads is not automatically faster. You have only one console on which the output can appear

Comment: _"Is the output expected?"_. Yes.  `std::cout` is not implicitly thread-safe.

Comment: @DrewDormann it is thread-safe on a single character level, but that doesnt protect from output getting scrambled

Comment: pleae focus on one question. 3. is offtopic

Comment: I suggest you to read about [Amdahl's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) and [Gustafson's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustafson%27s_law) laws. They are essential to understand why more threads is not always faster and how to make good utilization of multithreading

Comment: And don't ignore the fact that the costs of starting up and discarding a thread when you're done with it can exceed the time required by small tasks. It is really easy to write code that is SLOWER. Probably easier than writing code that is faster.

Comment: Side note: If you're running on conventional commercial hardware take timestamps like 5.07e-05 seconds with a grain of salt. `chrono` can provide time down to the nanoseconds, but limitations in the OS and computing hardware make sub-millisecond time iffy.

Comment: Another side note: Because threads can start running instantly, starting the timer after starting the threads may give bad results. Thread `A` might be done before thread `B` is even done constructing.

Comment: So how come some runs the multithreaded run is ~1000 times faster in runtime than the one-by-one run, and other times it is half as fast ? Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way of measuring time.

```
thread A(add, a);
```

Here, a thread object will be created and it might execute the function immediately (depends on the OS scheduler).

```
A.join();
```

Here, you are waiting for the thread to finish.

Your basic flow is

```
thread A(add, a);
start timer
A.join()
end timer.
```

So, your timer measures the time spent on waiting for the thread to finish + execution of a few unlucky threads.

Another thing, std::cout is not thread-safe.

Comment: `std::cout` is thread-safe. There is no data race when multiple threads write to `std::cout` at the same time. Though the synchronization is on a single character level. Not sure what is the right word, but "not thread safe" suggests that you have undefined behavior due to data race when writing from multiple threads but thats not the case, just output can be interleaved, but thats not about safety

Comment: I see, I changed the timer to start the line before "thread A(add, a)" and end the line after "thread J(add, j)". Is this the correct way ? Also, is there a thread-safe print function to choose from ? Also, the two total times I find are different each run and sometimes the multi-threaded one is faster and other times slower than the one-by-one part. Is that to be expected ? Thank you

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number you are right, it's thread-safe, but output might interleave.

Comment: @HusamChekfa if you add it before thread A(add, a), it will measure thread creation time + execution time + wait time to finish. Thread creation is expensive(memory allocation + system call). Thread joining is also expensive(system call). Since you are measuring some random time(by the time the measurement starts, some threads have already finished execution), your output is not reliable.